# Opening a file from the postinst script of a deb package

Tags: deb

Is it possible to open a file from the postinst script of a deb package in an external application? I'm creating an installer for my software and I want to open a `README.md` Markdown file at the end of the installation. Tried to use `xdg-open` from the postinst script but it fails as Markdown files are not recognized. Linking the Markdown file to a text file (using `ls -sf README.md README.txt`) results in it being open in the terminal of the installation process instead of opening whatever application the user have defined to open text files. This is close to useless as, by default, this terminal is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

To "open" a file in a noninteractive environment is not well-defined in the first place; so no, what you are asking cannot be done reliably.

There are situations such as `apt-cron` where there is not a human involved at all, let alone then the administrator logged in to an X session where something like `xdg-open` would make sense (and on a multiuser system, how would you figure out which logged-in user(s) should open the file?)

The way for a Debian package to alert administrators (and, to some extent, their users) to significant information is to ship a `NEWS.Debian` file. This is a text-only file with no markup facilities, but you could put in a brief message which refers to your Markdown file for more information.

Comment: Ideally, the file would be open for the user that double-clicked the installer package. I'm well aware that this will not be desirable in an automated installation scenario. Wondering if it's possible to know how the installation process was launched... But opening a file or a directory at the end of an installation process is easy from installers for e.g. MacOS X or Windows. Just looking for the same functionality in Linux systems as I prefer all my installers to behave similarly.